# Getting extra color while drawing two charts using flot js

Tags: flot

[image]Here my code

```
<div id="chart-revenue3" style="width:1100px; height:480px;" > </div>


         var series = [{
                data: [
                    [0, 100],
                    [1, 150],
                    [2, 125],
                    [3, 160],
                    [4, 95]
                ],
                label: "Generes",
                color:"#4598AE"
            },
            {
                data: [
                    [0, 104],
                    [1, 157],
                    [2, 178],
                    [3, 145],
                    [4, 78]], 
                label: "Playlists",
                color:"#8AA453"
            }, {
                data: [
                    [0, 55],
                    [1, 40],
                    [2, 60],
                    [3, 10],
                    [4, 20]
                ],
                label: "Home",
                color:"#A84745"
            }, {
                data: [
                    [0, 55],
                    [1, 40],
                    [2, 60],
                    [3, 10],
                    [4, 20]
                ],
                label: "Search",
                color:"#D98445"
            }, {
                data: [
                    [0, 55],
                    [1, 40],
                    [2, 60],
                    [3, 10],
                    [4, 20]
                ],
                label: "New and Hot",
                color:"#71598E"
            },
            {
              data: [
                    [0,150],
                    [1, 200],
                    [2, 250],
                    [3, 120],
                    [4, 90]
                ],
              label: "# Venues",
              points: { show: false },
              lines: { show: true,fill: false},
              yaxis: 2,
              color:"#81A0C1"
            }];

            var options = {
                xaxis: {
                    minTickSize: 1,
                    ticks: [[0,'Dafault'],[1,'Alternative'],[2,'Country'],[3,'Latin'],[4,'Rock']]
                }, yaxes: [
                        {                               
                        },
                        {                   
                            position: "right" , min:0, max: 1200,  tickSize: 200
                        }
                    ], 
                series: {
                    bars: {
                        show: true,
                        barWidth: .3,
                        align: "center",fillColor: {
                                            colors: [{ opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 1 } ]
                                        }                           
                    },
                    stack: true,
                    shadowSize:1
                },
                legend: { show: true, container: '#chart-revenue3-table' }
            };

            $.plot("#chart-revenue3", series, options);
```

so if i run this code am getting some extra color on bar chart..please give any idea
[image]

Comment: What do you mean? What part isn't what you expected? Can you put your code in a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: There is two chart ..on the stacked column chart line chart is coming but it creating some extra color fill on that..  http://jsfiddle.net/BrEJm/1

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't seem to include the stacking plugin? Are you using the stacking plug in?

Comment: Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BrEJm/2/) with the stacking plugin

Comment: I think your problem is with how the `# Venues` plot is interacting with the second axis. It's screwing up the placement of that bar. What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Your best bet might be to just make the `# Venues` series the first series in your set: http://jsfiddle.net/BrEJm/4/

Comment: I edited my question please have a look into it.The first image is what i want actually.But am getting the chart like second one.The venues values is causing error on chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, now I understand what you are trying to do. What you are missing is that you need to tell flot not to plot the `# Venues` series as a bar:

```
{
    data: [
        [0, 150],
        [1, 200],
        [2, 250],
        [3, 120],
        [4, 90]
    ],
    label: "# Venues",
    points: {
       show: false
    },
    lines: {
       show: true,
       fill: false
    },
    yaxis: 2,
    bars: {
       show: false             // <-- this is the bit you were missing
    },
    color: "#81A0C1"
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BrEJm/6/

The reason you  need to do this is because in your `options` you set:

```
series: {
    bars: {
        show: true,
        //...
    }
}
```

And the way flot works is that it will merge those default set of series options with whatever explicit options you set for each series. So, even if you don't specify, all your series inherit `bars.show = true`.

Comment: Great here.Its working fine but here i have one doubt as whether the line is plotted properly.because i feel the value [0,150],[1, 200],[2, 250],[3, 120],[4, 90] is not in correct position logically.Is that correct ?